# Guacamole Sitting out?

Tags: food-safety

So I find it odd, that every site says "Don't leave guac sitting out more than 2 hours or you'll get sick!"

But a lot of recipes (like alton browns for instance) actually say to let it sit out for a couple of hours at room temp?

Proof:
http://altonbrown.com/guacamole-recipe/

I ask because my buddy brought over some Guac for a cook out, and it was sitting in the house (at about 70 degrees so it wasn't super hot). And I think I ate some before we put it back in the fridge (and it had been out for about 3 hours).

(we got it from kroger, it was one of the ones they make fresh or whatever). It's still green and smells fine.)

So whats the deal?...2 hours too much yet a lot call for that. So if you let it sit out for 2 then serve it (and it sits out for 2 hours) thats four hours?

Thoughts?..am I probably ok?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Nobody is telling you "or you'll get sick"**

What they are telling you that it's unsafe. This is a completely different thing. You can eat unsafe food if you like. The people who publish unsafe recipes do it too. They just count on not getting sick.

**2 hours vs 4 hours**

The actual "danger zone" time is 4 hours. For foods you buy in their final, perishable state, it's down to 2 hours, because it's assumed that the first two hours got "used up" between producer, transport and seller. So it just so happens that 4 hours for a homemade guacamole (whose clock started ticking when you cut the avocado) is still safe. But this is a coincidence, you probably can find recipes somewhere which say to keep it out longer than 4 hours before serving.

**let it sit out for 2 then serve it (and it sits out for 2 hours)**

That's not what a recipe assumes. It assumes that you let it sit for 2 hours and then serve it and it gets eaten. The recipe creator assumes that you know enough about food safety to make your own decisions if your process is different.

Comment: This makes sense, I haven't gotten sick yet so I guess I scraped by lol.